# $W$ is binary R.V. and $Y= W\cdot Y_1 + (1-W)Y_0$, where $Y_1, Y_0$ are also R.V.s. Does $E[W\cdot Y]= E[W\cdot Y_1]$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Furthermore, assume that $W$ is independent of $Y_1$ and $Y_0$.

I think the answer is yes, because when $W=1$ $Y=Y_1$, and $W=0$ then $Y=Y_0$, so
$$\tag{1}
E[W\cdot Y] = prob(W=0) E[0] + prob(W=1) E[Y_1]
$$
because $W=1\implies Y=Y_1$, and similarly
$$\tag{2}
E[W\cdot Y_1] = prob(W=0) E[0] + prob(W=1)E[Y_1]
$$

Assuming I did not make  mistake then because (1)=(2) the answer is YES.

I am wondering how to formally prove this, though? I think the approach is to note that $$W\cdot Y$ is an RV that can take two values, $Y_1, Y_0$, which probability $prob(W=1)$ and $prob(W=0)$ respectively. Then note that the joint distribution of $W,Y$ can be written as the product of marginal and conditional distribution, and use the fact that the conditional distribution of $Y$ on $W$ can be used to simplify things (because there are only two outcomes).

I get a bit confused though because $W\cdot Y$ (and $Y$ are random variables whose values are random variables).

Also, is independence needed for the result to be true (assuming I am right)? I do not think so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $W$ only takes the values $0$ and $1$, it follows that $W^2=W$ and $W(1-W)=0$. Therefore
$$ WY=W^2Y_1+W(1-W)Y_0=WY_1 $$
hence
$$ \mathbb{E}[WY]=\mathbb{E}[WY_1]$$
Note that $W$ does not need to be independent of $Y_0$ and $Y_1$.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.